# Reference rails image in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a jquery function that's supposed to change the background of the page. I want the background to be an image in the app/assets/images directory. However, I'm confused as to the proper way to reference the image with the asset pipeline.

Here's the line I have now:

```
    $('body').css("background-image", "url('welcome.png')");
```

What's the best way to access the image in the url parameter?

Comment: What is wrong with the method you are currently using? Put the path relative to the page in between the parentheses: `url('app/assets/images/welcome.png')`

Comment: Do you have the gem "jquery-rails"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('body').css("background-image", "url('/assets/welcome.png')");
```

In order to access assets in the pipeline, you have to specify the `assets` folder.

I've been trying to find where I read this, but Rails basically converts all asset helper urls to something like `/assets/asset.png` or like `/assets/stylesheet.css` so you should be able to do the same by just specifying the `assets` folder in your source url.

Comment: This solution is outdated and I would recommend the answer from  @tirdadc below.

Answer (score 6):

This is covered in the documentation:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

You should use the methods described in "2.3.3 JavaScript/CoffeeScript and ERB", which would mean adding the .erb extension to your JS file, and using asset_path.

Another approach that's more elegant would be to move your image to a class definition in a css.scss file and then adding that class in your jQuery:

```
.welcome {
  background-image: url(image-path('welcome.png'));
}
```

and in your jQuery:

```
$('body').addClass("welcome");
```

Comment: This is a good answer, there is no problem with fixing the value of the url in the javascript. But that solution is not so good, I was going that way when I saw this (obvious) suggestion and changed my mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`$('body').css("background-image", "url('/app/assets/images/welcome.png')");` ?

Assuming app is at the document root.

Comment: When I do this, it just throws a 404.

Comment: It's impossible to help without your file structure and server configuration sorry :/

Comment: I don't think you need to specify the full app path.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, You need to use the .erb (embedded ruby) extension to allow rails path helpers in your .js files. If your js file (balabala.js for example) is in asset/javscripts/, change its name to balabala.js.erb, and then use:

```
$('body').css({"background-image":"<%= asset_path({'filenamehere.png') %>"});
```

Require this file in your asset/javscripts/application.js

```
//= require balabala
```

Then it should work